# how to remove duplicate text records from mysql table

Tags: mysql, database

I have two columns in my mysql table `words` and name of these columns are `wordid` which is primary key and other column is `lemma`.

I need to remove duplicate values of `lemma` from the table. Please tell me how can I do it with MySQL command. here is a sample of my table.

```
wordid    ||  lemma

+--------+--------------------+

 148206  || wilful disobedience 

 149162  || wilful disobedience 

 149857 || wilful disobedience
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to add a UNIQUE index on the `lemma` column. Include the `IGNORE` into the `ALTER` statement, so all the duplicates will be removed. Note that the next inserts with duplicates will throw an error.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE words
ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_lemma (lemma);
```

Comment: @Nisa, look at this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4cef0/1 . Everything working, maybe you provide the full queries step by step to reproduce the error? Or even better a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in once by using the following query:

```
delete * from table_name where wordid not in (select wordid from table_name group by lemma)
```

The inner query will select the first wordid for each lemma and ignore the repeated.
The outer query will delete all the rows which do not have word id from result of inner query. It will delete all other rows having repeated lemma.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a delete from inner join with subselect form get the wordid to not delete

```
  delete from  my_table a
  inner join  (
    select wordid
    from my_table
    group by lemma
    having count(*) >1 
  )  t  on a.wordid = t.word.id 
  where wordid not in (  select wordid_to_delete
    from (
          select min(wordid) as wordid_to_delete
          from my_table 
          group by lemma
          having count(*)>1
     ) t2

  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to identify which rows have duplicate primary key values:

```
      SELECT col1, col2, count(*)
       FROM t1
      GROUP BY col1, col2
       HAVING count(*) > 1
```

This will return one row for each set of duplicate PK values in the table. The last column in this result is the number of duplicates for the particular PK value.

If there are only a few sets of duplicate PK values, the best procedure is to delete these manually on an individual basis. For example:

```
    set rowcount 1
     delete from t1
      where col1=1 and col2=1
```

The rowcount value should be n-1 the number of duplicates for a given key value.

If there are many distinct sets of duplicate PK values in the table, it may be too time-consuming to remove them individually. In this case the following procedure can be used:

-- First, run the above GROUP BY query to determine how many sets of duplicate PK values exist, and the count of duplicates for each set.

-- Select the duplicate key values into a holding table. For example:

```
     SELECT col1, col2, col3=count(*)
        INTO holdkey
    FROM t1
     GROUP BY col1, col2
     HAVING count(*) > 1
```

-- Select the duplicate rows into a holding table, eliminating duplicates in the process. For example:

```
      SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
    INTO holddups
     FROM t1, holdkey
    WHERE t1.col1 = holdkey.col1
    AND t1.col2 = holdkey.col2
```

At this point, the holddups table should have unique PKs, however, this will not be the case if t1 had duplicate PKs.  For example,

Delete the duplicate rows from the original table. For example:

```
     DELETE t1
     FROM t1, holdkey
    WHERE t1.col1 = holdkey.col1
    AND t1.col2 = holdkey.col2
```

Put the unique rows back in the original table. For example:

```
     INSERT t1 SELECT * FROM holddups
```

Hope this helps!